# How to change "abc+dfg" to "'abc' +'dfg'"?

Tags: c#

I have a variable : `string str1 = "abc+dfg+..."`, I want to change str1 to `string str2 = "'abc'+'dfg'+..."` ?  Is there a simple way to achieve it ?

Comment: At first， I thought of using Replace. But I want to know whether have other efficient method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If string format is always as you described, you can do following trick:

```
str2 = "'" + str1.Replace("+", "'+'") + "'";
```

Comment: The method is more  efficient  than linq

Answer (score 1):

Is this simple enough?

```
string str1 = "abc+dfg";
string str2 = String.Join("+", str1.Split('+').Select(x => $"'{x}'"));
```

That gives:

```
'abc'+'dfg'
```

If you actually explicitly mean this:

```
string str1 = "abc+dfg+..."
```

Then you need to be slightly more complicated:

```
string str2 = String.Join("+", str1.Split('+').Select(x => x == "..." ? x : $"'{x}'"));
```

That gives:

```
'abc'+'dfg'+...
```

Comment: great! You are very professional. I understand it's a little difficult.

Comment: I did a test and find that using replace is more efficient than linq.

Comment: yeah, beacuse  str1.Length is very large. Thank you very much！ Let me learn much about Linq usage！